# Does BigQuery have a Max Bad Records "Per File" when ingesting from CSV?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am loading GCS files into BigQuery. And I can set a maxBadRecords setting for the load job that uses wildcards. However, what happens if I have 10 files, and 9 of them process good, but then the 10th file has a lot of bad records that exceed the maxBadRecords setting, it is going to revert that entire job.

Is there a way to set max bad records **per file** in BigQuery when creating a load from GCS job using wildcards?

Comment: How are you creating this job? Are you doing it by Cloud Console, the Classic UI, Command line or one of the Client Libraries?

Comment: I'm using client library.

Comment: which client library? and could you share the code?

Comment: I have this same question and more details that I am willing to provide if someone is will ing to provide an answer...